# simple percentange Calculation

Tags: objective-c

Please take a look at the following code and tell me why skillPercentange is always Zero:

```
NSInteger skillPercentange;
skillPercentange=totalCorrectAns * reloader/100;
```

Comment: What are the values of `totalCorrectAns` and `reloader` ?

Comment: tell us about totalCorrectAns and reloader, maybe some more core .. !?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want to do, but I'll try to show you a demo:

```
int allQuestions = 50;
int correctAnswers = 25;
float precentage = (100 * correctAnswers)/allQuestions;
NSLog("%i of %i questions answered correctly. That are %.1f percent!",correctAnswers,allQuestions,precentage);
```

> Output: "25 of 50 questions answered correctly. That are 50.0 percent!"

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales correct. Even though this might sound really weird to you, but your device isn't capable of calculating 10/100 without loosing some accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

```
float skillPercentange;
skillPercentange=(totalCorrectAns * reloader)/100;
```

or

```
skillPercentange= totalCorrectAns * (reloader/100);
```

according to  whatever is your formula.

```
NSLog(@"skillPercentange=0.1f",skillPercentange);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger skillPercentange;
skillPercentange = 100 * totalCorrectAns / reloader;
```